# What format should I use for a styleable attr if I am using it as argument of typedArray.getInt()??

Tags: java, android, xml, view

I have the following attr and I am using the following code with it (in myview.java). I have seen that there are many possibilities of format like: integer, boolean, color, enum, flags, float... I know that the code I am using with it is "getInt" that recieves two int arguments, so I have thought that it should be a integer, but I have seen also that there exists another function that is called "getColor" that also recieves two int arguments and the right format is color not the integer as I could thought, so I am a little bit confused on what format should I use for "type" in my case of using "getInt.

```
//in attrs.xml

 <declare-styleable name="Calendar">
        <attr name="type" format="" />

//in myview.java
        int cal = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.Calendar_type, 0);
```

Comment: Integer type............................

Comment: @Style-7 and why in the getColor() function if it recieves two int arguments they should be attr with format color instead of integer as getInt()? Could be color be a type of integer also?